# Objective-C/Cocoa: Properly loading UIViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Suppose I have created a `UIView`, `MyView`, in Interface Builder, and I have hooked it up (set its File's Owner) to my `UIViewController` class, `MyViewController`.

Now, I would like to present view.  It's just another view, so I don't want to present it as a modal view.

How do I go about displaying it?  Should I add it as a subview of my window?  If so, where does it go relative to my other views?  Should I present it as a view in its own right somehow, and disable the other views?  What is the mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want the app to act.

You can either add MyView as a subview of the current view using [UIView addSubview](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview:) if you are going to have a "Done" button or something like that on MyView to remove itself.

```
// show new view
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview: myViewController.view];
```

Or if you want the user to be able to navigate back to the main view(like in mail,notes etc) the most common way to do that would be to add a navigationController to your window and using [pushViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW2) to present your views.

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

I much prefer the navigationController approach in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingModelViewControllers/PresentingModelViewControllers.html